# Problem with blank line in interactive session

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In one of the sections of one technical document that I'm writing using reStructuredText I want to include a interactive session and this output.

Example:

```
>>> help(module)
    asdasd
    asdasd

    asdasd
```

When I process with sphinx-build to build a html output the output is not the expected because the blank line it breaks the block.

There is any way to fix the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks the block"? This question is unclear.

Comment: @StevePiercy: When Sphinx renders that, it ends the "example" after the second line of asdasd and the next adasd is treated as the beginning of a new rST paragraph unrelated to the example. So it's not inside the nice box that code examples go in, any actual Python after that isn't syntax highlighted, etc.

Comment: Would `.. code-block:: pycon` do what you need? https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.python.PythonConsoleLexer

Answer (score 0):

> Doctest blocks are text blocks which begin with ">>> ", the Python interactive interpreter main prompt, and end with a blank line.
> --[rST Markup Specification](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#doctest-blocks)

You may use an indented literal block or a ["code"](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#code) or "code-block" directive.

```
.. code:: pycon

   >>> help(module)
       asdasd
       asdasd

       asdasd
```